# Почему JavaScript не распознаект юникод?

Tags: javascript, unicode

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var stroke = document.createElement('div');
var elemStyle = stroke.style;
elemStyle.position = 'absolute';
elemStyle.top = '50%';
elemStyle.left = '50%';
elemStyle.fontSize = '50px';
elemStyle.color = 'red';
elemStyle.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
uniStroke = String.fromCharCode(04AD) + String.fromCharCode(1072)
stroke.innerHTML = uniStroke;
body.appendChild(stroke);
```

Почему выдает, что код неверный?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое "код неверный"?

Comment: ```document.write("\u04AD");``` - ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: Потому что вы в javascript не указали правильную систему счисления этого числа